# How to use textfieldParser to edit a CSV file?

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, textfield

I wrote a small function that reads a csv file using textField line by line , edit it a specific field then write it back to a CSV file.

Here is the code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = @"C:\file.csv";
        String dpath = @"C:\file_processed.csv";
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
            {
                String line;

                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };



                while ((line = parser.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                      string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();

                     if (parts == null)
                     {
                         break;
                     }                   

                          if ((parts[12] != "") && (parts[12] != "0"))
                          {

                              parts[12] = parts[12].Substring(0, 3);
                              //MessageBox.Show(parts[12]);
                          }

                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dpath, false))
            {
                foreach (String line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("CSV file successfully processed ! ");
        }
    }
```

The field I want to edit is the 12th one (parts[12]):

```
for example : if parts[12] = 000,000,234 then change to 000
```

the file is created the problem is it does not edit the file and half the records are missing. I am hoping someone could point the mistake.

Comment: Did you debug through this? Probably then you can easily make out the problem.. what strikes me is that you do not update the parts[] in your innermost loop, so the line will never be split into parts.

Comment: try adding `writer.Flush();` before the writer is disposed

Comment: @Dan-o Not needed.  The writer is disposed, which closes the stream, which also flushes the stream.

Comment: Entirely possible.  I knew `Dispose` called `Close`, was unaware that it called `Flush` as well.  `Flush` is not called automatically by `Close`.

Comment: @Dan-o Yes, it is.  When you close the stream it's flushed.

Comment: hmm.  I'll have to check into that.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: If you are working with large files - you should consider reading a line and then immediately writing the corrected line out. Otherwise you are reading the entire file into memory before writing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call both `parser.ReadFields()` and `parser.ReadLine()`.  *Each* of them advance the cursor by one.  That's why you're missing half the rows.  Change the `while` to:

```
while(!parser.EndOfData)
```

Then add `parts = parser.ReadFields();` to the end of the loop.  Not having this is why you're edit isn't being seen.

You can also remove:

```
if (parts == null)
{
    break;
}
```

Since you no longer have `line`, you'll need to use the fields to keep track of your results:

```
lines.Add(string.Join(",", parts));//handle string escaping fields if needed.
```